# How to parse multi level custom key valued JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this Json string, A and B can be custom names sent from my server.

Json String

```
{
    "basketContent": {
        "A": {
            "Apples": "22",
            "Avocado": "43"
        },
        "B": {           
            "Banana": "62",
            "Blueberry": "1"
        }
    },
    "basketOwner": "Anne"
}
```

Javascript

```
var jsonData= JSON.parse(jsonString);

  for (var i in jsonData.basketContent) {
       var c= jsonData.basketContent[i];
       console.log(c.[0][0]);
   }
```

How Can I iterate through the basketContents without the need to name it? is there workaround?

Comment: for-each isn't good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could recursively iterate through the object:

```
 var obj = {
    "basketContent": {
        "A": {
            "Apples": "22",
            "Avocado": "43"
        },
        "B": {           
            "Banana": "62",
            "Blueberry": "1"
        }
    },
    "basketOwner": "Anne"
};

function print(obj,key){
    if(typeof obj == "object"){
        for(var key in obj){
          print(obj[key],key);
        }
    }else{
       console.log(key);
       console.log(obj);
    }
}

print(obj);
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/eEQLW/1/

Comment: Should you check for `obj.hasOwnProperty( i )`. Is this required with json objects?

Comment: Thanks. any idea of how to fetch key valued inside the A ?

Comment: @Macon key is now included in example/fiddle